# Is there any better way to take place of videoview.seekto()?

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

Here we want to play some other video where the main video comes to some exact time point . Since videoview.seekTo can not achieve what we want,we have to run a thread to catch the time point by videoview.getCurrentPosition that is exact as we all know.
In fact we can only use start() and pause() instead of using seekTo(when some other video prepare to start or just finished)to make the video continue from the right exact time point.
followings is our effort.

```
private VideoView vv;
public void load(String url) {
    if (null != proxy)
       proxy.destory();
    proxy = new HttpGetProxy1(9980);
    this.url = proxy.getLocalURL(url, true);
    vv.setVideoPath(this.url);
    vv.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            Log.e("onCompletion");
            state = VideoState.stop;
            ivStart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ivStop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ivPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (null != callback)
                callback.onComplete();
       }
    });
    vv.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
       @Override
       public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
       }

    });
    vv.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            Log.e("setOnErrorListener:" + what + "-" + extra);
            load(ComponentVideo1.this.url);
            return false;
        }
    });
    clearTimer();
    if (null == callback || null == questions || questions.size() == 0)
        handler.post(runnable);
}

private Handler handler = new Handler();

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        timeFormat.setText(getTimeFormat(vv.getCurrentPosition()) + "/" + getTimeFormat(vv.getDuration()));
        handler.postDelayed(this, 100);     
        if (null == vv || null == callback || null == questions || questions.size() == 0 || index >= questions.size())
            return;
        if (vv.getCurrentPosition() < questions.get(index).getMsec())
            return;
        callback.call(questions.get(index++));
    }
};
```

To achieve that,in the runnable,the postDelay time was reduced from 500 to 100(0.5s to 0.1s).But there's a great pressure running the method every 0.1s.
What's more disappointed is that we need to do changes on each video resource we gonna to play

Answer (score 0):

This code sniplet is from a Button click listener in onCreate. It is used for seeking and pausing small amounts of time, approximately a few hundred milliseconds. It updates a text box until the video view plays the the desired time, and then pause.

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!checkBox1.isChecked()&&loaded1) {
            if (frame1Advanced) msec = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
            msec += msecAdd;
            videoView.requestFocus();
            videoView.start();
            while (videoView.getCurrentPosition() < (msec-20)) {
                textView1.setText(getMilliToString(videoView.getCurrentPosition())+ "+" + (int)(videoView.getCurrentPosition() - msec));
            }
            videoView.pause();
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer,but unfortunately we must put a listener on the main video and passively leaded to a new video.The voluntary event can not match it.If we take the ’while‘ loop to runnable... that seems to be a fine choice ,gonna have a try.